# how to tell in python, using email, if an email has been seen

Tags: python, email

I'm using python 2.6.6 and have imported email.
I can read the emails fine, but how can I check the flag to see if the email has been seen?

I have

```
import email

msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
```

now I need

```
beenSeen = msg.flag('seen')
```

or what ever it should be

Comment: Seen by whom? Where? This is not a property of an email message.

Comment: Is this an IMAP facility? I think you need [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html).

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I am using IMAPLIB to connect to the server.  What I am trying to do is display the email as either read or not.  So as I am getting all the emails from the server and displaying them, I need to know if they were read or not.

Comment: The messages don't know whether they have been read or not, that is a property of the server.